# Connect to Azure Mobile Services from dynamic HTML content in WebView

Tags: javascript, azure, webview, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I am able to load the HTML/JavaScript sample provided in Azure mobile services quickstart if I follow the instructions. But that sample involves hosting the webpage on localhost.

My requirement is to display a similar webpage that communicates with WAMS in an existing windows phone application. I added the three files (index.html, page.js and style.css) into the project and navigated to index.html in a webview.

It doesn't seem to connect to azure mobile services. I added app name in CORS whitelist with no luck. Is it absolutely necessary to host the page somewhere in order to connect to azure mobile services? If not, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation of Internet Explorer in general.  Example, see: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2012/06/19/enhanced-protected-mode-and-local-files/

Better idea is to encapsulate your page in an Apache Cordova app - this allows you to use pretty much the same stuff, but with an explicit content-security setting.  At this point, you should be using Azure Mobile Apps (not Mobile Services) and there is a tutorial here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-get-started/

Comment: Thanks Adrian,

I followed the first link you provided by adding the following to my HTML:
<!– saved from url=(0014)about:internet –>

Now it works on windows phone. Is it expected to work on android/iOS too?

Comment: I wouldn't say "expected" - it depends on the browser used to open and their specific requirements.  Unfortunately, these things change all the time, so what works today may not tomorrow.  Your better chance is to encapsulate in an Apache Cordova app so you can be assured it will work.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. I'm having a hard time working with Apache Cordova app. I am now very close to implementing this the way I originally wanted to. I got it to work on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE. But cannot get it to work in Windows Mobile webview control. I am using NavigateToString() method and I am getting the html (with inline javascript and css) string from database. I have added * and null in CORS whitelist. In javascript debug console, I see that it is sending "about:" as the origin. I tried adding "about:" in CORS whitelist, but it won't let me add (it says ':' is an invalid character).

Comment: I also tried adding "about*". But the same error appears in JavaScript console hinting that I need to do something about "about:". What should I add in CORS whitelist in this case?